# Detecting multiple key press in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to detect a number of key combinations in javascript. I need to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>, <kbd>Right</kbd>, and <kbd>Left</kbd>.

So far I'm just trying to detect when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed. Here's what I have ([JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/gFcuU/507/)):

```
var keys = {};

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    keys[e.which] = true;

    printKeys();
});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    delete keys[e.which];

    printKeys();
});

function printKeys() {
    var html = '';
    for (var i in keys) {
        html += '<p>i: ' + i + '</p>'
        if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if ($.inArray(17, keys) > -1) 
            html += '<p>ctrl was pressed, return val: ' + $.inArray(17, keys) + '</p>'
    }
    $('#out').html(html);
}
```

I guess I don't really understand how JQuery's `inArray` is supposed to work because when I press *any* key, it just returns -1. The if statement also evaluates to true while I only want it to do that when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed. How can I fix this so that my if statement properly detects <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> being pressed? I'll be able to figure the rest out once I get that working properly.

EDIT: Changed if-statement to evaluate `inArray` returning `> -1`

Comment: [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray) <-- probably a good place to start if you don't understand how it works :)

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Thanks Andrew, if statement now reads `if ($.inArray(17, keys) > -1) ` Still doesn't pick up 17 being in the array despite `html += '<p>i: ' + i + '</p>'` popping out 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript you would need to capture the value of the `window.event.ctrlKey` to detect if the control key is being pressed.  Here is an example of a function that would use to block pasting from the clipboard into a field using the `ctrl+v` keyboard shortcut:

```
    function BlockControlV() {
        var keyPressed = window.event.keyCode;
        var ctrlPressed = window.event.ctrlKey;
        if (ctrlPressed && keyPressed == 86) {

            var ClipBoardData = window.clipboardData.getData('Text')
            ClipBoardData = trim(ClipBoardData)

            if (ClipBoardData != '') {
                if (isNaN(ClipBoardData) == true) {
                    window.event.keyCode = 0;
                }
            }
            else {
                window.event.keyCode = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Though not exactly relevant to what you're trying to do, you should be able to figure out what direction you should be heading.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to find out whether the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> is pressed, is to test the `event` object for the `ctrlKey` property:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    console.log(e.which, e.ctrlKey);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gFcuU/512/).

I would have provided a more relevant demo, but I have no idea what that demo's meant to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

First, keys is not an array- it is an object. So instead of the 2 separate if blocks in your function, you can write simply:

```
if (keys.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
  ...
}
```

Secondly, jQuery appends a very convenient property to event objects: `ctrlKey`.

In your keydown event handler, wrap the call to `printKeys` in an if statement:

```
if (e.ctrlKey) {
  printKeys();
}
```

Finally, to detect whether ctrl + (any other key), simply check whether the `which` property on the event corresponds to one of the [keyCodes](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) you are looking for

Comment: Understood. Though this answers my question of detecting the ctrl key, I don't see how I can use this to detect `ctrl + left` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You're missing braces `{}` for the else case.

***[js Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gFcuU/510/)***

```
if (i == 17) {
    html += '<p>ctrl</p>';
} else {}
```

Run the Demo & watch the text "ctrl" show up while you click `Ctrl` key.

`e.ctrlKey` is the easiest way to detect the Ctrl key click.

To detect Ctrl + left ***[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ELSHN/)***

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 37 && e.ctrlKey)
        alert("Control + Left Clicked"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect it easily using the returned `event` object. This object also contains information about all `control keys`:

- `ctrlKey` - does the `Control` key was pressed?
- `shiftKey` - does the  `Shift` key was pressed?
- `altKey` - does the if `Alt` key was pressed?

All of these properties are `boolean` values (`true`, if button was pressed, otherwise` `false`).

Here is the demosntration of aforementioned properties in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uzvvr/).